# Facebook API and PHP - getLoginUrl() - never shows dialog and breaks on other FB account

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the Facebook API and it's doing strange things - I have two issues:

1. When I use getLoginUrl(...) - I never get a popup - I don't click anything and it just redirects.
2. Using my FB account this code redirects and i see the 'user' and 'token' but when I try the same thing on a workmates FB account it gives the error "An error occurred. Please try again later".

Here's my code for the redirector:

```
require_once '../../src/facebook.php';

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID',"xxx");
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET',"xxxxx");
define('REDIRECT_URI',"http://dev.example.com.au/php/work/redirectSimple.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user == 0) 
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI));
    echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");
}
else
{
    echo ("<script> window.location.href='".REDIRECT_URI."'</script>");
}
```

And my redirected code ( redirectSimple.php ):

```
echo "\n WELCOME!";

require_once '../../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => "xxx",
  'secret' => "xxxxx",
  'fileUpload' => true,
  'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo "\n user = ".$user;

$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo "\n token = ".$token;
```

I've also tried these things on another machine with the same outcome.
So, Maybe it's an account or App settings issue?

Comment: "Maybe it's an account or App settings issue?"   Answer: yes.

Comment: What is your actual question?  What do you expect to happen versus what actually happens?

Comment: Hi TR, this is just a very basic test to isolate what the error is about. I'd like to see the popup if it's still a part of the API. Also, I'd like to find out what settings I need to change to fix the error on the other FB account.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't go looking for a popup with PHP, unless you are using Ajax, as PHP doesn't do popups, being server side. If you want the popup you need to use the JavaScript SDK.

Secondly, after a successful login, you are redirecting to another file. Personally I would use require_once rather than a redirect, as you have already created a Facebook object and if you redirect you will have to recreate it.

If you couple that with "try" and "catch" you can trap any Facebook errors which will give you a clue as to what is going on.

Other than that, as the other person said, check you aren't in sandbox mode in the app settings.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no code here to create a 'popup' - `getLoginUrl()` creates a url you can use as part of the server side flow - you need to redirect to this url.
2. Your co-worker is most likely not a developer or tester of your app, and so cannot see it (it's probably in sandbox mode)